# What is the quantum mechanical explanation for the speed limit of light?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, speed-of-light

What is the quantum mechanical explanation for the speed limit of light? Does it arise from more fundamental principles?

Comment: There is the approach to explain it in terms of vacuum fluctuations of charged particles allowed because of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle: [Mainland & Mulligan, Foundations of Physics 50(5), 457–480, "Polarization of Vacuum Fluctuations: Source of the Vacuum Permittivity and Speed of Light" (2020)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10701-020-00339-3). See also my question on it: [Why is the speed of light in vacuum frequency-independent?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/605811/why-is-the-speed-of-light-in-vacuum-frequency-independent)

Comment: And [Does the speed of light in our definitions take vacuum energy into consideration?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/603235/does-the-speed-of-light-in-our-definitions-take-vacuum-energy-into-consideration)

Comment: The speed of light isn’t explained by QM. You can have SR without QM and QM without SR.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/230703/50583 and its linked questions

Answer (score 4):

So far as we know, there is no quantum mechanical reason for the speed of light $c$ to be an absolutely limit.  The limiting speed is a consequence of special relativity, and the validity of special relativity has nothing to do with the validity of quantum mechanics.  You can have a consistent non-quantum yet relativistic theory; or you can have a consistent nonrelativistic quantum theory.  As it happens, the actual universe is both quantum and relativistic, but quantum mechanics does not necessitate relativity.

Answer (score 0):

Standard quantum mechanics is not even compatible with relativity. If you try to calculate the probability of a particle being found at the time $t$ at the position $\mathbf{x}$, given that it was measured at $\mathbf{x}_0$ at the time $t_0$, you find that $$P(t,x)=\left(\frac{m}{2 \pi i (t-t_0)}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}} \exp \left(i m \frac{\left|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_{0}\right|^{2}}{2 (t-t_0)}\right)$$ which is non-zero everywhere, implying that you can find the particle anywhere in the universe.

As you can see, there is no limiting speed.